# Cypher query to check node connectivity

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm new to neo4j and would really appreciate your help for this.

I have following graph created in neo4j.

n1----n2----n3----n4---n5

n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 all are nodes
--- : relationship_type_1 (REL)

Now given any set of nodes (in any order), I want to check whether these nodes are connected or not.
E.g. Given n1, n2, n3          ==> Connected.
     Given n1, n3, n2, n4, n5  ==> Connected.

How should I formulate my cypher query to check connectivity?

Following query is working even if I change the order,

```
MATCH p=_1--_2--_3 
WHERE _1.name?="Node1" and ALL (n in nodes(p) 
  WHERE n.name IN ["Node1", "Node2", "Node4"]) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

on http://console.neo4j.org/?id=xl8pnl

but if I provide start nodes instead of using _1,_2 and change the order then it's not returning me the path. :(

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=xl8pnl
for following query,

```
START p1=node(6),p2=node(5),p3=node(4) MATCH p=p1--p2--p3 
WHERE p1.name?="Node1" AND ALL (n IN nodes(p) WHERE n.name IN ['Node1' ,'Node3', 'Node2' , 'Node4']) 
RETURN nodes(p)
```

it doesn't return the path as nodes are connected in node(6)-node(5)-node(4) order.

Comment: Do the nodes have to be connected directly or are nodes in between allowed (the found path can be bigger than the nodes set, e.g. n1, n3, n5 -> n1----n2----n3----n4---n5 = connected) ?

Comment: HI,
Nodes should be connected directly. 
E.g. given, n1,n3,n5 should result in ==> Not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list the different patterns that constitute the "connectedness" to you for instant by listing them explicitly like 
[console.neo4j.org/r/2w3poz](http://console.neo4j.org/r/2w3poz)

```
START p1=node(0),p2=node(4),p3=node(5) 
RETURN 
  CASE 
    WHEN p1--p2--p3 OR p2--p1--p3 OR p1--p3--p2 OR p3--p2--p1 OR p3--p1--p2  
    THEN 'Connected'  
    ELSE 'Not connected' 
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 1:

2 paths found

```
MATCH p=_1--_2--_3--_4 
WHERE _1.name?="Node1" and 
  ALL (n in nodes(p) 
    WHERE n.name IN ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3", "Node4"]) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

Check it out here:

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=nn9yl6
in this case order dosen't matter

---

Case 2

(no path found)

Use node 1,2,4

```
MATCH p=_1--_2--_3 
WHERE _1.name?="Node1" and ALL (n in nodes(p) 
  WHERE n.name IN ["Node1", "Node2", "Node4"]) 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

Check it out here:

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=xl8pnl

Comment: Just a small quick follow up question. Are these nodes returned in-order every time?
e.g. 
MATCH p=_1--_2--_3--_4 
WHERE _1.name?="Node1" and 
  ALL (n in nodes(p) 
    WHERE n.name IN ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3", "Node4"]) 
RETURN nodes(p);

returns 

[(6:Node {name:"Node1"}), (5:Node {name:"Node2"}), (4:Node {name:"Node3"}), (3:Node {name:"Node4"})

will it return nodes in this order every time? (in order in which they are connected)

Comment: They will come in the order of `p` so it's the same every time according to the path.

Comment: Hi,
The answer works perfect for the query you provided but for the same scenario if I have nodes specified in START and if I change the order of connectivity then it doesn't work. Please point out where I'm making the mistake. Following is the query.

START p1=node(6),p2=node(5),p3=node(4) 
MATCH p=p1--p2--p3 
WHERE p1.name?="Node1" AND ALL (n IN nodes(p) 
                                WHERE n.name IN ['Node1' ,'Node3', 'Node2' , 'Node4']) 
RETURN nodes(p),p1

it returns the path but if I change the order

START p1=node(6),p2=node(4),p3=node(5) 


doesn't return the path.